# Input checkbox in <a> with ng-click

Tags: html, angularjs

I have situtation like this:

```
<a ng-click="doSomething()">
   Text
   <input type="checkbox"/>
</a>
```

And if I want to mark the checkbox it does doSomething() instead and checkbox remains unchecked.
I know that it is easy to say to just put  outside  but I really can't do it so don't offer that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<a ng-click="doSomething()">
   Text
   <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="boxChecked" />
</a>
```

Then in your `$scope.doSomething()` function add an assignment `$scope.boxChecked = true`.

- [`ngChecked` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

Comment: Good answer! Almost solves my problem but in your case the checkbox gets checked also if I click on the Text. Is there a way to check the checkbox only when I click on the checkbox?

Comment: @RVstack oh haha, then how about you do `<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="boxChecked" ng-click="checkTheBox()" />`, and move that assignment `$scope.boxChecked = true` from `$scope.doSomething()` into `$scope.checkTheBox()`

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle input by follwoing way:

```
<!--temlate-->
<a ng-click="doSomething()">
   Text
   <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="myModelProperty"/>
</a>

//controller
$scope.doSomething = function(){
  $scope.myModelProperty = !$scope.myModelProperty;
}
```